# How to insert data into hive table by changing date column?

Tags: hive

I am new to Hive.I need to insert data into a table by changing the date column. I tried below code it did not work:

```
insert into table t1 
select * from tt2 
alter t1.fulldate = 2018-07-31 00:00:00.0 timestamp;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your select query **`specify all column names`** and for `fulldate` column keep the value as your `required timestamp value`.

**Try with below syntax:**

```
insert into table t1 select col1,col2,timestamp(2018-07-31 00:00:00.0) fulldate from tt2;
```